# Web service programming

Tags: java, spring, web-services, maven

I am new to web service programming and developed my first web service using Axis2 implementation. I have successfully executed my first web service program, but I can see some folder within WEB-INF in error state. After creating the simple class file I have converted it into Web Service and after converting it I can see some folder within WEB-INF in error state.

[image]

Similarly the admin folder within WEB-INF folder too have some error file.
Can some one tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Eclipse will show you in the error view what is wrong

Comment: There is an error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver                                          I had earlier resolved this issue by adding the xmlschema-core-* jar files to the lib folder of WEB-INF as the same error was displaying when  I was whether my service was deployed on the server using the link (http://localhost:8080/applname)

Comment: I have added the same jar files and refreshed my project but still can see those error folder within WEB-INF folder

Comment: Can you see the jar files in your build path? (Right click on project -> Build path -> Configure)

Comment: The said JAR file is present under Web App Libraries in Libraries tab.

Comment: It should work then. Please try to rebuild the project (Project -> Clean). If this also does not help, you can try restarting eclipse.